# What is the the French word for a mathematical set?

Tags: mathématiques

Quel mot pour phrase les mathématiciens français utilisent-ils pour des collections, des ensembles de nombres ou des conteneurs de nombres?

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ∩ {4, 5, 6, 7} = {4, 5}
```

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ∪ {4, 5, 6, 7} = {1, 2, 3, 4 , 5, 6, 7}
```

Les mathématiciens américains utilisent le mot "**set**"

Comment: Wikipedia is often a good and easy tool to find a word in a foreign language. [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) and then change to French and you get it.

Comment: I agree with @None, this is a dictionary question, VTC.

Answer (score 3):

En français, on utilise le mot "*ensemble*" (terme fondamental de la théorie des ensembles et des mathématiques qui dépendent de cette théorie (correspond à "set" en anglais)) ; dans certains contextes le terme "*collection*" peut être utilisé et on peut l'utiliser comme synonyme (comme en anglais (collection)), mais ça ne se fait pas très souvent. Le terme "*classe*" est aussi utilisé, bien que plus précisément une classe soit un ensemble d'ensembles (comme en anglais (class)) ; il est utilisé de cette façon anormale dans la théorie des relations d'équivalence par exemple : les "*classes d'équivalence*" correspondant à une relation d'équivalence sont en fait des ensembles (comme en anglais (equivalence class)) ; dans ce contexte "ensemble d'équivalence" ne signifie rien, c'est un terme qu'on ne peut pas  utiliser comme synonyme de "classe d'équivalence".

Les ensembles constitués par des ensembles, c'est à dire des ensembles dont les éléments sont eux-mêmes des ensembles, sont souvent appelés des *familles* ou, terme long, *famille d'ensembles* (théorie des ensembles, algèbre, topologie, analyse).

Comment: Dans la documentation Microsoft c# en anglais,  une liste comme  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} est appelée "collection" et, dans la documentation française, c'est aussi "collection" https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections#BKMK_SimpleCollection.  Toutefois, comme indiqué par LPH, le bon terme est "ensemble" (ou éventuellement "groupe").

Comment: En mathematiques, on utiilise "ensemble" pour la structure algébrique "ensemble", et ce n'est pas substituable à "classe" (une classe est plus grosse qu'un ensemble, sauf les "classes d'équivalence" qui sont bel et bien des ensembles) ni à "groupe" (qui est une autre structure algébrique). "Collection" ne me semble pas bien défini en algébre, puisque l'ensemble a déjà très peu ou pas de structure, mais on l'utilise informellement.

Comment: @Graffito Microsoft ne représente pas les mathématiques françaises ni même américaines ou aucune autres Les informaticiens peuvent très bien utiliser leurs propres termes mais ils mettent leur discipline en marge. Le mot « groupe » ne peut pas être utilisé à la place de « ensemble » ; un groupe est strictement une structure algébrique consistant d'un ensemble sur lequel est défini une opération ; par exemple l'ensemble des nombre entiers avec l'opération d'addition est un groupe, (1/2)

Comment: @Graffito que l'on dénote « (Z,+) » ; Z est l'ensemble, mais en fait « + » est aussi un ensemble, un type d'ensemble particulier que l'on appelle « fonction » (+:Z² → Z), une fonction définie sur le produit cartésien de Z avec Z et dont les valeurs sont dans Z (assez simple en fait, ce n'est qu'une systématisation de ce que l'on sait après l'école primaire, mais elle a une utilité très grande). (2/2)

Comment: @Frank Appeler un ensemble une structure algébrique est une erreur que seulement pourrait faire un journaliste qui commence à s'intéresser aux mathématiques en vue de vulgariser certaines notions. Un étudiant de l'algèbre ne la ferait pas ; la première notion fondamentale de l'algèbre que l'on doit assimiler c'est q'une structure algébrique est une paire ou un triplet ou nuple qui consiste d'un ensemble, d'une ou plusieurs opérations, et d'une ou plusieurs relations (0 relation est possible). Un ensemble n'a pas besoin d'opérations pour exister (1/2)

Comment: @Frank alors qu'il n'y a pas de structure algébrique sans opération (ou semi opérations lorsqu'on considère des choses plus simples). Il n'est pas du tout question d'opération dans la définition des ensemble de Halmos (*Naive Set Theory*) et il n'y en a pas dans la définition de Zermelo et Fraenkel. (2/2)

Comment: @LPH - ok, j'ai parlé trop vite, Bourbaki dit que "structure" commence quand on impose une structure sur un ensemble. On pourrait pinailler pour dire qu'un ensemble est une "structure vide". Mais Bourbaki commence bien son étude des structures algébriques par les ensembles, dont il faut bien parler avant de parler de "structures".

Comment: @LPH Si on voulait vraiment, on pourrait dire qu'un ensemble est une "structure" avec l'unique opération identité, mais cela n'aurait pas d'intérêt.

Comment: @LPH Par contre, si l'on se penche sur la précision des notions, une "classe" serait une "collection d'ensembles", précisèment pas un "ensemble d'ensembles", suivant les axiomes que l'on se donne. Dans le cadre de ZF, C = { x: P(x) } est une classe, alors que E = { x dans A: P(x) } est un ensemble, en utilisant le schéma d'axiomes de compréhension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145494/discussion-between-lph-and-frank).